# Unable to use a new dataset column crystal syntax

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Reports 13 with Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Here is a fragment of Crystal Report using crystal syntax formula that works:

```
if {covDataSetTable.passFail1} = true then
    b := a + "<b>Passed</b>"
else
    b := a + "<b>Failed</b>";
```

`covDataSetTable` is a DataSet stored in an xsd file. I added a new column `passFail1s2` in `covDataSetTable` and need to access it in a similar formula:

```
if {covDataSetTable.passFail1s2} = true then
    b := a + "<b>Passed</b>"
else
    b := a + "<b>Failed</b>";
```

Now Crystal Reports reports that there is an error in the formula. It expects there to be a string instead of `true` in the first line:

```
if {covDataSetTable.passFail1s2} = true then
```

Why is that? How to resolve it?

Comment: what is the datatype of `{covDataSetTable.passFail1s2}`

Comment: @Siva: How can I set datatype of dataset's column?

Comment: I am unaware of `C#` just had experience on Crystal reports.. I guess there is datatype mismatch..

Comment: @Siva: I'm new in this field - manipulating crystal reports in VS.

Comment: @Siva: Found it in the property.

Comment: Great... what was the issue? can you share?

Comment: @Siva: I didn't know that I could right click on a column to view its property from the xsd file. From the property of any column, one can change the data type of that column. I changed the type to bool and updated the data source in crystal report. This resolves the problem.